# Как протестировать web сайт/приложение, используя unittest?

Tags: python, юнит-тесты

Как протестировать web сайт/приложение, используя unittest? Какие модули использовать? Желательно с примерами кода такого теста?

```
import unittest

class test_website(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_website(self):
        self.assertEqual(website('http://example.org/category/page'),
            'Ответ от сервера')
```

Answer (score 2):

Сначала нужно разобраться с матчастью: какие тесты нужны, для чего, тесты чего именно. Я бы посоветовал прочитать [вводную статью про тестирование на Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/121162/), [раздел про тестирование из Гайд ту Питон](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/tests/) и [раздел про тесты из документации к Джанго](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/) – это не займёт больше часа, а понимания должно добавить значительно.

За примерами тестов можно сходить на Гитхаб. Например, посмотреть на тесты в [сорцах mosowpython.ru](https://github.com/moscowpython/moscowpython).

Comment: Тест на то, что будет показано пользователю в браузере.

Comment: Тогда в доках Джанги есть всё, что нужно. Вот, например, [документация к test client](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/tools/#the-test-client). А вот – [похожий тест из moscowpython](https://github.com/moscowpython/moscowpython/blob/master/apps/meetup/tests/test_views.py#L20).